# Django crontab automated setup issue in ubuntu development server

Tags: django, ubuntu, gunicorn, supervisord, django-crontab

Am on a windows10 local development and has I can't use cron am testing in a development server.

my working basecommand

```
from api.models import EnrolmentUniquePattern
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
import datetime
from django.utils.timezone import get_current_timezone

class Command(BaseCommand):
    
    help = 'Expires enrolment unique pattern objects which are out-of-date'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print(EnrolmentUniquePattern.objects.filter(
            expiration_date__lt=datetime.datetime.now(get_current_timezone())).delete())
```

Am trying to setup django-crontab in a ubuntu 16.04 server and having a couple of issues.

```
pip install django-crontab
```

have it on my installed apps and requirements.txt

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
 ...
 'django_crontab',
 ...
]
```

In the development.py settings that extend a base_settings.py have the cronjobs:
Only trying to test a job that I already tested via command

```
CRONJOBS = [
    ('* * * * *', 'proregattaapi.cron.my_cron_job', '>> /var/log/django_cron_job.log'),
]
```

the cron.py:

```
from datetime import datetime

from django.utils.timezone import get_current_timezone
from api.models import EnrolmentUniquePattern


def my_cron_job():
    print('my_cron_test')
    EnrolmentUniquePattern.objects.filter(
        expiration_date__lt=datetime.datetime.now(get_current_timezone())).delete()
```

then pushed to the server hosted by digital ocean.

SSH into the server, activated the virtual environment and made the calls:

```
python manage.py crontab add
python manage.py crontab show
python manage.py crontab run 3a55bd7591de350aa5d5d7be7758f17c
```

in the above, got confirmation that the job was running, with the crontab run command. Did the job that was deleting models with an expire datetime shown above

but when I did:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

or left supervisior run the development server

the job didn't start or logged anything

Then I looked at:

```
crontab -e
```

and the output was:

```
* * * * * /root/.python-virtual-environments/proregatta-django-development-new-virtualenv/bin/python 
/var/www/development.proregatta.com/manage.py crontab run 3a55bd7591de350aa5d5d7be7758f17c >> /var/log/django_cron_job.log # django-cronjobs for proregattaapi
```

From my limited knowledge, I was thinking that crontab did the following:
a django crontab install and living inside the running project would be sufficient.

Am I not activating the virtualenv before the cron running?

What am I missing?

Thank you in advance!

UPDATE:

```
CRONJOBS = [
    ('*/1 * * * *', 'proregattaapi.cron.my_cron_job', '>> /var/log/django_cron_job_test.log 2>&1 '),
]
```

started outputting the print:

```
print('my_cron_test') # line to /var/log/django_cron_job_test.log
```

but does not perform the call to delete.

Any advice ?

But when i force run the job does the call to delete the objects..

**Different implementation**

wasn't able to do it with django-crontab. So created an .sh script that basically does the same.

here is my script for my context to work:

```
#!/bin/bash
#chmod a+rx clean-expired-tokens.sh run when edited
cd ~/.python-virtual-environments/proregatta-django-development-new-virtualenv/bin
source activate
cd /var/www/development.proregatta.com/
python manage.py check_enrolment_unique_pattern_expiration --settings=proregattaapi.settings.development
deactivate
```

after enabling the execution of this file:
opened:

```
crontab -e
```

edited to run once a week at sunday, and to log to that file:

```
0 0 * * 0 /root/clean-expired-tokens.sh >> /var/log/django_cron_job_test.log 2>&1
```

and this is with what I will going for now.

from what I understood (django-crontab) was detecting the virtual environment calling its python and trying to run the command but somehow it wasn't running in the venv.

Comment: Hey man, were you able to find a solution for this? Once I deploy on digital ocean i have the same problem. It looks like cron is not installed on the digital ocean machine.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue, while running chron tab on my native ubuntu machine, it was not showing anything to the logs, using ubuntu 22.04

```
#MyApp/settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django_crontab',
    ....
]

CRONJOBS = [
    ('* * * * *', 'crontab.cron.my_cron_job')
]
#MyApp/cron.py
def my_cron_job():
    print("The Chron Job")
```

Do Make sure that everything is in place like installed apps, urls
Now to the issue that you can't see anything related to cron on ubuntu

**Intstall Postfix on Ubuntu**

```
sudo apt install postfix
```

here is the docs for installation : [Ubuntu Postfix install](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/mail-postfix)
just click okay and configure(If you don't want anything else)

on your root directory `/home/<username>`

type `cd /var/mail`

list there using this command `ls`

and you should see a file with your username, if you do `cat <username>` you should see that your cron has worked there

```
.......
Date: Tue, 13 Jun 2023 21:13:01 +0530 (Timezone)
The Chron Job
```